# wp.editor.initialize does nothing

Tags: javascript, wp-editor

I'm trying to add additional `wp_editor` instances when a user clicks an "Add content" button in the back-end. I have it mostly working, except that the user needs to save the post after adding the field in order for the TinyMCE editor to appear, as it's initialized with the PHP `wp_editor()` function.

After some digging, I found the `wp.editor.initialize()` ([docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.editor)) JavaScript function, which seems like it should initialize a new editor given a textarea's ID.

This doesn't seem to work, no matter what I try. I have the following code:

```html
<textarea id="custom-tinymce-testing" name="custom-tinymce-testing"></textarea>
```

Which I try to initialize with JavaScript after clicking a button:

```js
wp.editor.initialize("custom-tinymce-testing", {
    mediaButtons: true,
    tinymce: true,
    quicktags: true,
});
```

This doesn't appear to do anything; the textarea remains unchanged, and no console errors are thrown. Running `console.log(wp.editor.initialize())` does show that the function exists, so I don't think it's an ordering thing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This was way simpler than I thought it was – even on `post.php`, you need to run `wp_enqueue_editor()` before using `wp.editor` in JavaScript. I had assumed that I wouldn't need to do that, because an editor was already loaded.